# Blog software / platform available for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blogs

I'm a Java geek and I've started writing a blog (using Wordpress), but blog customization is a pain as PHP is not my thing, and I also want to make it part of my website -- login/session/etc should work out of box.

I know of [Pebble](http://pebble.sourceforge.net/), but it does not support Google App Engine[GAE], as it writes data to XML files.

Does anyone know of any other Java blogging platform [possibly GAE compatible] like Wordpress?

Comment: Why not take the chance to learn PHP?
There are lots of docs about customizing wp and easy to follow guides.
Not putting it as an answer since it's just a suggestion.

Comment: yes, even i know basic PHP which is enough for WP, but you know, using java blog will help learning other aspects of java like hosting/maintaining own site in java in which I am new. and it is now mandatory for me.. see my profile.. I just started my own company. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache Roller](http://rollerweblogger.org/project/) would be a good one, but I think its only the server part. And Pebble ofcourse!

Also find a list of open source bloggers in java [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/bloggers).

Comment: Great stuff! Any idea on how many of these are supported for the mobile platform? ( to be more specific: there's a wordpress plugin for the android. Any of the mentioned blogging platforms have something similar? )

Comment: Most of them are inactive these days including Apache Roller & Pebble.